# Time complexity for merging two BSTs?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

So if I have two trees t1, and t2, I would take the maximum of t1 and ensure that it is smaller than the minimum of t2. If I then merge the trees by bringing T2's minimum to the root, what is the time complexity of this operation and why?

Comment: After you've checked that MAX(t1) <= MIN(t2), the operation to 'merge' the trees is O(1).  You remove the MIN(t2) node from its place in the tree (fixing up what's left behind, which is tricky if the minimum node is not a leaf node).  You then make the node's left pointer point to t1, the right pointer point to t2, and you're done.

Comment: Because once you've extracted MIN(t2), the remaining operations are constant time operations.  However, finding and extracting MIN(t2) is not O(1) in general.  It depends on whether you've got a more or less balanced tree or not.  In the worst case, it is an O(n) operation as the maximum entry is the root of t2, and all the nodes in descending order are pointed at by the left nodes of the next larger value.  If the tree is more or less balanced, finding MIN(t2) becomes O(log.N).  .

Comment: Do you know in advance that `MAX(t1) <= MIN(t2)`?

Comment: @shapiroyaacov no because the original q is to remove nodes in a given range so i am making a delete function to delete the nodes, which calls this join function

Comment: So when the join function is called you know that `MAX(t1) <= MIN(t2)`, no?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler since this is a simple BST (not balanced according to the question) we can just add the root `t2` as a new child of `MAX(t1)`

Comment: @shapiroyaacov oh yes i guess we would know that max(t1) is less than mint(2)

Comment: @shapiroyaacov — yes, but that then ignores the part of the question that says "by bringing T2's minimum to the root".  It would also be possible to insert root(t1) as a new node (the left child node) of MIN(t2), the complement of your suggestion.

Comment: @shapiroyaacov — Also note that by extracting MIN(t2) and then dangling the trees below it, you get a better balanced result than attaching either complete tree at the appropriate place on the other tree.  You could presumably extract MAX(t1) and dangle the two trees below that, too.